# Import non modular scripts (linq.js) in Aurelia

Tags: ecmascript-6, aurelia

I have a question about importing script which define global variables to aurelia using import keyword. We can simple import modules but what about scripts like linq.js which define global variable Enumerable? Is this possible to execute that script to define that namespace?

I tried to do steps from [this blog post](http://khornberg.github.io/articles/mousetrap-with-aurelia/) but it's defines only non static methods. So I can't for example use `Enumerable.from` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue for the package manager, jspm. When you have a module that exports a global, you need to configure a [shim](https://github.com/jspm/registry/wiki/Configuring-Packages-for-jspm#shim) in your jspm configuration file where you specify the name of the exported global(s).

In the case of linq.js, however, it seems that it does use `module.exports` (I am looking at [this source here](https://github.com/mihaifm/linq/blob/master/linq.js)), so it should just work out of the box. If it doesn't, try [specifying the module format](https://github.com/jspm/registry/wiki/Configuring-Packages-for-jspm#format) (cjs) in the configuration.

Import like this:

```
import Enumerable from 'linq';
```

Comment: I don't know what i did wrong earlier but now it works like you wrote. Thanks!

Comment: `import * as Enumerable from 'linq';` worked for me.